# What are the unique effects of the six new legendary weapons introduced in Borderlands Game of the Year Edition?

Tags: borderlands-goty-edition

Borderlands Game of the Year Edition introduces six new legendary (orange) weapons. What are their unique (red text) effects, and what do they do?

Comment: to be clear, which version of Borderlands are you talking about-- the original, Borderlands 2, or Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel? i haven't found anything online in regards to GotY weapons for BL1-- in fact, the only thing i'm seeing is the four DLC missions and maps, the game itself, and a map of Pandora.

Comment: @EarthToAccess The original Borderlands was re-released a week ago with updated textures and UI.  This is what he's referring to.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2ma66eRVRI) shows all the new legendary weapons with their red text, but does not seem to go into detail about what the effect is (unless its the text directly below it)

Comment: @MBraedley oh, i haven't even seen anything on that. that's kinda cool actually.

Answer (score 2):

The six new weapons are:

1. **Sucker Punch** -  Machine Pistol with +500% melee damage. "*Your shoelace is untied...*"
2. **Mug Shot** - Burst Rifle with high base damage, low magazine size, low zoom scope. Will always be Explosive element x1. "*Does your face hurt? It's killin' me...*"
3. **Hive Mind** - Rocket Launcher that is burst-fire, 3 shots per trigger pull. Very large blast radius. "*That's gonna leave a Marx*"
4. **Silent Night** - Pump-Action Sniper Rifle with +800% Critical hit damage and a low zoom scope. "*It knows when you're awake*"
5. **Baha's Bigger Blaster** - Combat Shotgun with +150 Melee damage, fully automatic. "*Giving you a leg up on the competition!*"
6. **Violence** - Revolver that is always explosive x3, with a small magazine and no sight. The lower your health, the higher the damage dealt. "*Death will reign.*"

Here's my source, a great video by Joltzdude139 talking about the weapons and showing some gameplay with them.